# Behavior call back not functioning using $Model->query()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I created a behavior and attached it to models using `$actsAs`.

`beforeFind()` and `afterFind()` are working when using `$Model->find()`, but **not** when using `$Model->query()`.

Why are these methods not called when calling `query`?

Answer (score 2):

### Model query invokes no callbacks

[The function query](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.0/cake/libs/model/model.php#L2409-L2421) has no callbacks, it is intended to be used for raw sql queries only:

```
function query() {
    $params = func_get_args();
    $db =& ConnectionManager::getDataSource($this->useDbConfig);
    return call_user_func_array(array(&$db, 'query'), $params);
}
```

Note the absence of [code for triggering callback methods](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.0/cake/libs/model/model.php#L2062-L2078).

If you're expecting callbacks to be ran (and arguably, if you're using query *at all* to find data) you're using the wrong method - you should be calling `find`.